# What to do with a leftover question after a ragedelete?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, deleted-comments

A (very) recent user posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23722139). It was deemed unclear and several user requested clarifications. Apparently not understanding why we didn't understand him, he finally deleted all his comments and replaced the text of the question with periods. What should be done ?

Comment: It's not very helpful to post a [link without title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23722139) to a question that is bound to get deleted within a handful of hours... Just to give us some basic context: what was the original title? And in brief what were the clarification requests? Were the clarification requests clearly-phrased, relevant and reasonable? etc?

Comment: I don't remember the title, and I don't know the policy for deletion. The clarification requests were crystal clear: essentially, "give an example" (four times, if I remember correctly).

Comment: That tells us nothing at all about how unclear/clear/good/bad/useful/useless/relevant/irrelevant the original question was, what the topic was, what the user's level of English and clarity are like, whether the clarification requests were relevant and reasonable or not, whether the user's subsequent behavior was reasonable or not. This almost contains no information at all.

Comment: Deleting the question body and replacing with periods cannot be considered reasonable in any case. Not in a world of grownups.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Simply roll-back the change (or let a user with full edit privileges do it).

If the OP persists in defacing their content, don't start an edit war - flag for moderator attention and explain what's happening.

Comment: Can the OP delete his own question (using delete link) even with 1 rep point?

Comment: Yes, but only if there's no more than one answer, and no positively scored answer.

Comment: @Mat - in this case, the OP (of this meta question) posted a positively scored answer. So no way to delete the question outside a mod/high-rep user